# How to properly solve the following probability problem?

Tags: probability, problem-solving

I'm looking for the formalization of the solution to the following problem:

Consider the random experiment which consists of drawing two cards from a fair deck of 52 cards. What is the probability of getting two aces given that the first card was not put back into the deck after the first drawing?

The answer I know lacks of formality. To me, the previous random experiment should have as sample space the set:

$$\Omega =\{(\omega_1, \omega_2): \omega_1\ \textrm{and}\ \omega_2 \ \textrm{are cards from the deck}\}.$$

Then we should define:

$$A_1=\{(\omega_1, \omega_2): \omega_1\ \textrm{is an ace}\},$$

and

$$A_2=\{(\omega_1, \omega_2): \omega_2\ \textrm{is an ace}\}.$$

Then we are looking for the probability of the event:

$$A_1\cap A_2=\{(\omega_1, \omega_2): \omega_1\ \textrm{and}\ \omega_2\ \textrm{are aces}\}.$$

This should come from:

$$P(A_1\cap A_2)=P(A_1)P(A_2|A_1).$$
But how can I compute $P(A_2|A_1)$ using the above formalism?

As a matter of fact, the event $A_1\cap A_2$ does not capture the event ``both cards are ace, given the fact the first card is out of the deck''.

Comment: Note that there are $52\times 51$ equally likely possible outcomes to the experiment.  Make sure you can understand why.  How many of these equally likely outcomes correspond to both an ace as the first and as the second card?

Comment: Does your $\Omega$ definition include the condition that the two cards drawn are distinct, or do $52$ of the elements of $\Omega$ have probability $0$?

Comment: @JMoravitz Yeah, I understand, in the second drawing there will be one less card in the deck. The problem is how to write the sample space properly.

Comment: @Henry What do you mean by "52 of the elements of $\Omega$ have probability $0$"?

Comment: .... write it however you want so long as it is understandable both to you and your reader.  Letting $D=\{A\clubsuit, A\diamondsuit, \dots, K\spadesuit\}$ be the set of cards, then $\Omega = \{(a,b)\in D\times D~:~a\neq b\}$ for instance and is of size $52\times 51$

Comment: $(A\spadesuit,A\spadesuit)$ has probability $0$.  So too does $(7\diamondsuit, 7\diamondsuit)$ and the others should be obvious.  Are they in your $\Omega$?

Comment: @Henry, sure, that is right.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks, now I understand how it works =)

Answer (score 1):

Just use Bayes' Theorem: $\mathsf P(A_2\mid A_1)~=\dfrac{\mathsf P(A_1\cap A_2)}{\mathsf P(A_1)}$

Which should match the intuition:

> When given that the first card is an ace, there are 3 aces among the 51 remaining cards that could be drawn second.